# How to find Astaia?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Can't pass quest "The Sister's Pendant" because can't find those sister (Astaia).

Where should I look for her? Quest arrow show that i'm somewhere close... but I can't find her... what is a trick?

Thanks!

Comment: According to [WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=29324), it should be the same NPC you talked to to begin the quest in the first place.

Comment: Wowhead is your friend for pretty much any question related to questing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Astaia](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=4156#comments) is the Darnassus Fishing trainer, so should be right where the guards tell you (on the south island in the middle of the city.  If she isn't there, she may have been killed recently.

If you're looking for the actual pendant ("Aquinne's Moon Pendant") for the quest "[The Sister's Pendant](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=29324)", you need to fillet (use) the quest fish you pull out of the water--they contain the quest item.